# how can i draw multiple rectangles in a picturebox in c#?

Tags: c#

hi  i need help with this i wanna draw multiple rectangles  with my function myrectangle but it just draw the last one and erase the first one i dont have much practice with graphics so please help this is what i tried

```
private void MyRectangle(int p1, int p2 )
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
        {

            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black),p1,p2,30,30);
        }
        this.pictureBox1.Image = myBitmap;


    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MyRectangle(120,120);
        MyRectangle(180,120);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everytime you call your functon you replace your image

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = myBitmap;
```

you either need multiple pictureboxes, or draw multiple rectangles in your image.

for the later, try something like

```
        private void MyRectangle(Graphics g, int p1, int p2)
        {           
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black), p1, p2, 30, 30);           
        }

        void GraphicFor(PictureBox pictureBox, Action<Graphic> draw)
        {
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
            {
                draw(g);
            }
            pictureBox.Image = myBitmap;
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicFor(this.pictureBox1, g =>
            {
                MyRectangle(g, 120, 120);
                MyRectangle(g, 180, 120);
            });

        }
```

(Note, I haven't compiled the above)